# How can I prevent itunes to sync mp3 files in downloads folder?

Tags: itunes, ipod

So I have a 30gb ipod and I am using the latest iTunes.

When I connet my ipod to my mac I see that mp3 files in downloads folder are copied to my iPod which I do not like at all.

How can I prevent this?

I only want to sync albums I buy from the store and the cds I import.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to prevent your device from syncing automatically.

Open iTunes Preferences and select the Devices tab.

To prevent iPod, iPhone, and iPad devices from syncing automatically, select the option below:
"Prevent your device from syncing automatically"
[image]

After you select this option, reconnect your device.

You can than select music you do want to sync. You can also use smart folders to sync selective music.

source [support.apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1351)

Comment: But I want to sync automatically? But only albums I buy from the store and the cds I import.

Comment: You can than select music you do want to sync. You can also use smart folders to sync selective music.